# Oracle How To Set Pivot Table Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table columns like **Question_Id, Department_Id, Value.**

Here is my data:

[image]

[image]

I want to get a table like this:

Here is my code:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT question_id, department_id,  TO_NUMBER(value)
        FROM   my_pivot_table)
        PIVOT  (SUM( TO_NUMBER(value)) AS sum_quantity FOR (department_id) IN (11 AS a, 12 AS b, 13 AS c, 14 AS d, 5 as e))

ORDER BY question_id;
```

I get this error but i dont what is wrong

```
  ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

EDIT:

I released that my value column is varchar. So i changed my code a bit but still i havent get my pivot table.

Comment: Make sure that datatype of `value` is number and no need to write quotes in the list `(11 AS a, 12 AS b, 13 AS c, 14 AS d, 5 as e)` should work.

Comment: And some sample data please?

Comment: i changed my code. thanks

Comment: If you provide some sample data, then it would be easy to help you. just looking at your query will not necessarily help.

Comment: i added a sample data if i get what you mean correct. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to move parenthesis:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT question_id, department_id,  TO_NUMBER(value)
        FROM   my_pivot_table  -- right parenthesis was here
        PIVOT  (SUM( TO_NUMBER(value)) AS sum_quantity 
                FOR (department_id) IN (11 AS a, 12 AS b, 13 AS c, 
                     14 AS d, 5 as e)))  -- and moved here
ORDER BY question_id;
```